# Declare two or more variables with the same name within the same scope

Tags: c, variables, scope

Is it possible to declare two or more variables with the same name within the same scope in C. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int a;
    int a;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Are you just curious?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can declare them only in multiple nested or disjunct scopes.

Comment: Oddly, you can have `static int x; extern int x;` at file scope. However, in spite of looking different, they refer to the same object.

Comment: future impossible tense

Comment: How would you reference one of them?  'a++' which gets incremented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible.

From the standard, **6.7 Declarations** (emphasis mine):

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be **no more than one declaration** of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) **with the same scope and in the same name space**, ...

As to *no linkage*, **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers** (emphasis mine):

> The following identifiers have **no linkage**: an identifier declared to be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a **block scope identifier** for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

---

This, for example, is valid at file scope (with internal or external linkage).

```
int a;
int a;
int a;
```

However, here all declarations refer to the same object.

Comment: This answer the question for identifiers with no linkage, but there are also external linkage and internal linkage.